# Wordpress the_content() outputting doctype declarations

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a fresh wordpress theme using the [html5blank](http://html5blank.com/) boilerplate theme for wordpress. 
For some reason when I call the_content() I get the following wrapping the actual content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
```

I couldn't detect any filters affecting the_content().

It doesn't occur when using get_the_content(), but I need to use shortcodes and the ability to auto-embed videos in the theme, so using that isn't ideal.

Any ideas where the unwanted tags/declaration is coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function yourCustomShortCode() {
    ob_start();
    echo 'your custom sort code starts';
    echo 'your custom sort code ends';
    ob_get_clean();
}
```

Try this it might work.

Using **ob_get_clean** you will be able to get your post content in the_content() function.

Comment: Right now I'm hoping to make the_content() work without outputting the doctype and html tags. There's no issue with shortcodes, the issue occurs even when there are no shortcodes present

Comment: Okay than for this you need to do below things.

First-of-all Disabling plugin one by one and see when it is fixed.
And secondly Editing wp-config.php and adding define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); to look for errors

Comment: Awesome, didn't occur to check the plugins earlier. Found the problem.